# Cancel more than one unit with siunitx and cancel

Tags: siunitx, cancel

Please see the behavior in these different examples. There's clearly something about `\text` command in the SIUnit `qty` doing something that I don't understand. But I'm using this all over my work, so finding a solution to be able to cancel the entire unit (including the text) would be great. The last option does work, but it requires me to constantly be separating the num and unit from each other so I can apply the cancel correctly which is less than ideal.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}

\DeclareSIUnit{\soln}{\ensuremath{\text{solution}}}
\DeclareSIUnit[inter-unit-product=\,]{\mlsoln}{\milli\liter\soln}

\begin{document}
$\qty{500}{\mlsoln}$

$\qty{500}{\cancel\mlsoln}$

$\cancel{\text{testing a text}}$

$\qty{500}{\cancel{\text{testing a text}}}$

$\num{500}\cancel{\unit{\ml}\text{ solution}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what in your context "solution" means- Maybe volumne of solution? In such a cases you may consider to use `siunitx` qualifier for units. For example

```
\DeclareSIQualifier\sltn{sol.}
```

or longer version

```
\DeclareSIQualifier\sltn{solution}
```

and than write

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier\sltn{sol.}
%   \DeclareSIQualifier\sltn{solution}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
$\qty{500}{\mL\sltn}$,\qquad \qty{500}{\cancel\mL\sltn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or when for qualifier is used whole word "solution"

[image]

BTW, so far `\gty` doesn't allow to cancel composed units. Canceled will be only the first.

Comment: The whole point of cancelling is to match stuff up, so one would expect to do it step-wise ...

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, this is part of a larger equation. I didn't think I should show the whole thing to avoid complicating the issue. But the units are part of a larger unit conversion. I will have to consider if this qualifier option will work as well, but the students are not used to seeing it presented this way (as a subscript like that)

Comment: @JM The format of qualifiers is controllable